# Passing a struct through a pipe to a child in C

Tags: c, struct, pipe

So I need to pass a struct through to a child process via a pipe. I've called the pipe `fileStatusPipe`.

So here's the parent code passing the structs through the pipe:

```
close(fileStatusPipe[0]);

//Some Code

while ((dirEntry = readdir(directory)) != NULL)
{
    write(fileStatusPipe[1], &dirEntry, sizeof(dirEntry));
}

close(fileStatusPipe[1]);
```

And here's the code for the child process:

```
struct dirent * data;
close(fileStatusPipe[1]);
while(read(fileStatusPipe[0],&data,sizeof(data)) > 0)
{
    printf("%ld: %s\n", data->d_ino, data->d_name);
}
close(fileStatusPipe[0]);
exit(0);
```

While the correct number of entries are printed, the entries are empty. That is to say, the correct number of structs are passed; however, their contents are empty. Why is this, and how can I correct this?

Comment: Add more code. How does your struct looks like?

Comment: In the child, you use `sizeof(data)` but `data` is a _pointer_ -- not what you want. Use `sizeof(struct dirent)`. Likewise for parent, so you need something that passes the length of the entire struct. Also, in the `write`, use `dirEntry` and not `&dirEntry` (they are different). In child, use `struct dirent data` and `sizeof(data)`

Comment: @TonyTannous I can add more code, but the struct is that defined in <sys\dirent.h>. I'm passing file status entries.

Comment: What platform is this? The size of `d_name` and therefore of `struct dirent` is not necessarily well-defined on all platforms.

Comment: To quote Linux' manpage on `readdir()`: "*POSIX.1 explicitly notes that this field should not be used as an lvalue.  The standard also notes that the use of `sizeof(d_name)` is incorrect; use `strlen(d_name)` instead.  (On some systems, this field is defined as `char d_name[1]`!)  By  implication, the use `sizeof(struct dirent)` to capture the size of the record including the size of `d_name` is also incorrect.*"

Comment: @Dolda2000 If it's `readdir(3)` [and it probably is], the size is fixed because it has `d_name[256]`

Comment: @CraigEstey: That happens to be true on Linux with glibc, but as the manpage I quoted says, it isn't necessarily so on all platforms, which is why I asked.

Comment: @Dolda2000 It is `readdir(3)`.
@CraigEstey What you said in your first comment just sank in. I feel a bit silly now, passing reference to `dirEntry`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*Caveat:* This assumes your `readdir` is `readdir(3)` vs `readdir(2)` -- See `man 3 readdir` (vs `man 2 readdir`).

Here is the [corrected] parent:

```
while ((dirEntry = readdir(directory)) != NULL)
{
    write(fileStatusPipe[1], dirEntry, sizeof(struct dirent));
}
```

And the child:

```
struct dirent data;
close(fileStatusPipe[1]);
while(read(fileStatusPipe[0],&data,sizeof(data)) > 0)
{
    printf("%ld: %s\n", data.d_ino, data.d_name);
}
close(fileStatusPipe[0]);
exit(0);
```

Otherwise, it's a bit more elaborate, involving `d_reclen`.